# Find out used encryption in an SQLite database

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to see from a string which encryption an SQLite database uses? Let's say, I can open the database and see this: `O45dTrA6NKG6SYeCENMwV7nxp66HR9lbhK12NGHgVnzEhebMjMJUhTmConk=` - how do I know which encryption is used? And how to decrypt it (should be alphanumeric in original)?

Comment: Looks like base64 encoding but the resulting data is not alphanumeric.